# Windows Mobile - What scripting platforms are available?

Tags: windows-mobile, scripting, system-administration, administration

We have a number of users with Windows Mobile 6 and need to apply minor changes. eg. update a registry setting. One option is push and execute an executable file using our device management software.

I'd like this to be a little more friendly for the admins who are familiar with scripting in VBScript/JScript etc. What are the options for scripting on Windows Mobile devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once option that the devs over at xda-developers seem to enjoy is [Mortscript](http://www.sto-helit.de/index.php?module=page&entry=ms_overview&action=view)

I have never bothered to use it, but I have used many cab installers that distribute mortscript so that they can do various tasks

Answer (score 6):

I work on windows mobile full time and have never really come across a good Windows Mobile scripting implementation unfortunately.  For some reason MS has never seen the need for it.  For example, even though you can actually get a command console on WM, it does not support running batch files, even though all the commands are still there and it would be relatively easy.  There is definitely not a VBScript engine I've ever heard of nor JScript.  There is [PythonCE](http://pythonce.sourceforge.net/) but the WM specific support is minimal and you don't get access to a lot of WM only things.

Also, I've done a lot of work with a company called [SOTI](http://soti.net/) which has a product called MobiControl that does incorporate a basic scripting engine. Though most of the commands are specific to their system and actually have to be run from a desktop-side management console.

Given all of the times I have tried to find a good scripting engine for WM myself you would think I would've just written one ;)

So, sorry, but the basic answer is *no*, there is not a scripting engine available for VB in the context that you specified.

Comment: Hey Adam, Wikipedia claims that there is a version of Windows Scripting Host for Windows CE 3.0 - which implies to me that it has VBScript support. Do you know if this is true? See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host#Version_history

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing to a scripting environment on Windows Mobile is the Configuration Service Provider interface.  While it is not a scripting language *per se*, it does allow one to do a lot of the same type of things such as modify registry settings, copy and delete files and directories, install and uninstall applications and much more.

Mike Calligaro has [a great article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc500581.aspx) on how to write scripts and how to get them from your desktop onto the device in various ways.  One of them is certain to work for you.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a [Visual Basic Runtime](http://www.cebeans.com/) to run VBScript

Answer (score 0):

**Try Lua:**
Oficial Lua page: http://www.lua.org/ 
Lua WinCe / Mobile port: http://www.magma.com.ni/sw/wince/lua/