# VBScript And Windows Mobile

Tags: windows-mobile, vbscript

I've started learning VBScript because of PowerShell, but I want to know if I can run VBScripts(**.vbs*) in a Windows Mobile device. Thanks.

Comment: What do you see as the relationship between vbscript and PowerShell? Your statement doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Simple: When I was starting to use PowerShell I've saw a article about VBScript, then I started learning.

Comment: I don't get it. What does VBScript have to do with PowerShell or vice-versa? The two are not related to each other.

Comment: In the site that I was reading about PowerShell and at the sidebar I see a article about VBScript. Then I started reading about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was searching deeply hard in the Google pages, then at the page 23 I think. I see this: [CeBeans](http://www.cebeans.com/), it's a Visual Basic runtime for Windows Mobile.

Then, it's possible! **:D**

Comment: Just looking at that site hurts my eyes.

Answer (score 2):

I dont think Windows Mobile supports it. This question [Windows Mobile - What scripting platforms are available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28820/windows-mobile-what-scripting-platforms-are-available) might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 0):

Convert to .exe file and you can run it on mobile.